# Hitting a plateau in my PhD research: what to do?

Tags: phd, research-process, supervision

3rd year in my PhD (AI in Healthcare field) ,
i read a lot and experienced different methods to come up with some novality or improve any older method results, with no luck.

not sure what to do now.

i cannot think of any new method, and this field is not my supervisor speciality and he can't help me.

Is that it? I do not want to give up, but there is nothing I can think of that can be considered as new to this field or significant.

What shall I do?

Comment: This is where you need to talk to your supervisor(s).  A good supervisor will always know where to go or has a set of novel research questions just in case a student is stuck.

Comment: Odd that you’ve exhausted the field already. What is something that, if it could be done one thousand times faster or a thousand times cheaper, would be influential in the world of healthcare? Is there a connection to your research? What if you tried to explain your research to-date to family and friends? What sort of reactions do you imagine you’d get if you did? Research, at least professional research, sometimes means looking for connections outside of your immediate environment. .

Comment: Many papers write something about "future research" or what still needs to be done. Many of the authors of these papers then don't do it themselves. Also on conferences such things are mentioned, and you could ask the authors whether this is something that they'd hope that other people do. Frankly I'm a bit surprised - 3rd year is quite late to discover that you don't have a proper research project and to wonder what to do about that.

Comment: For the love of God, please use proper grammar in your post (e.g., capitalising the first letter of sentences).  You are a doctoral candidate and this is a forum open to the scrutiny of the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI is a data-heavy field. Obviously, not reading anything at all and trying to come up with stuff on their own typically only causes irritation, but if all you do is reading, thinking and running models on the same old dataset which is dusting in some archives for a decade and has hundreds of papers on it, well, either you get a golden nugget or nothing at all, and chances for the former are rather slim.

Oftentimes, a solution to an "AI problem" is going to the field and talking with actual experts in the subject area. Lots of your assumptions about how they collect this data etc. might turn out to be completely off, and discussing some edge cases, outliers and whatnot gives valuable insights. Despite what glamorous ads about AI/ML ("sit in front of your pc and deliver sexy results everyone swoons over on a daily basis with the power of your brain alone") tell people, working on tools themselves is a big part of the job for a relatively minor part of researchers: typically, more time is spent understanding the requirements, sometimes exploring better ways to collect data and so on. If you discover that quite likely the source of major confusion for you model is, say, hair color (and it is not included in the data), trying to collect it and include it into analysis might be super valuable not only for the model performance but for the understanding of the field in general.

So, go to the field, rub some shoulders, try to understand data collection procedures and how your results could be used by experts. Best of luck!

Comment: In the OP's case, should the OP talk to healthcare experts? Or better yet, become a healthcare expert and then apply AI?

Comment: @scaaahu "better yet, become a healthcare expert" - no, that is an entirely different specialization requiring A LOT of time (easily over 10 years in some cases) and a different mindset. So my answer is: talk to healthcare experts, a lot. Whoever wants to dabble in AI research should be prepared to be figuring out the subject topic. It is no good if one works on, for example, H&E stained cell microphotographs not knowing which parts of the cell are basophilic and which are eosinophilic, and all there exists for them is ROC AUC/F1/whatever.

Comment: It is just hard to imagine for me that OP is 3 years in and completely out of both ideas and results if they have discussed their work a lot with those who supposedly will be using it...

Comment: @Lodinn I tried multiple methods and spoke to many, there are areas of improvements in the field, but every method I try I end up with no improvement!

Comment: @asmgx What do you call a "method" in this context (as in, is it a NN architecture/type of NN architecture/non-NN approaches?)? Also how much time approximately did you spend per approach? Your understanding of the task and even the task itself should be evolving, and I have really hard time thinking of the scenario of working on a project for a few years and not producing any knowledge. Your goal is more broad than "achieve higher accuracy than SOTA on a given set" - even taking the same SOTA algorithm and applying it to some subsets could produce valuable insights...